# Solr returning 400

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

here is the object model.When i try to commit Product to Solr, returning `unknown field loca`

```
public class Product
{
    [SolrUniqueKey("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [SolrField("manu")]
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

    [SolrField("cat")] // cat is a multiValued field
    public ICollection<string> Categories { get; set; }

    [SolrField("price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [SolrField("inStock")]
    public bool InStock { get; set; }

    [SolrField("loca")]
    public Location Location { set; get; }
}

public class Location
{
    [SolrField("zipcode")]
    public int Zip { set; get; }
    [SolrField("country")]
    public string Country { set; get; }
}
```

Is nested classes legal with solr?

why is it failing to store? when i remove `[SolrField("loca")]` it works fine.

how do you store such classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do nested classes in Solr. So you will need to flatten the location information into the Product class. However, you can then represent it a nested class within your application, by mapping the data into/out of Solr as needed.

As an example, update your Solr schema to store a loca_zipcode and loca_country field and then  map those perhaps in a new SolrProduct class defined like the following:

```
public class SolrProduct
{
    [SolrUniqueKey("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [SolrField("manu")]
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

    [SolrField("cat")] // cat is a multiValued field
    public ICollection<string> Categories { get; set; }

    [SolrField("price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [SolrField("inStock")]
    public bool InStock { get; set; }

    [SolrField("loca_zip")]
    public int Zip { set; get; }

    [SolrField("loca_country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map the `SolrProduct` flattened class to your `Product` class with the nested `Location` class.

Another alternative would be to use [dynamic fields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Dynamic_fields) in Solr and the dynamic mapping support in SolrNet using a Dictionary. Please see the [SolrNet - Mapping](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Mapping) section of the SolrNet wiki for more details and examples.

Comment: I see, that s fine. I ll do that. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I was kinda hoping solr does it for me. :)